# Table Cells Overlapp on Small Screens

Tags: css, html-table, whitespace, tablelayout

The cells on the table on https://dev.meteo.cam/pricing overlapp on small screens:

[image]

Granted, this table is a bit special, because I changed the style such that the `tbody` becomes vertically scrollable.

However, what is confusing is that the code sample below works, using the same CSS styles:

```css
table.table-complex {
  width: 200px;
  /*added only for this snippet to simulate small screens*/
}

table.table-complex tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow: auto;
}

table.table-complex tbody tr,
table.table-complex thead {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-complex">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Webcam</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>FTP upload <small>(up to every 5 min)</small><sup>1</sup></td>
      <td><b>free</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RapidFire FTP upload: <small>(up to every 5 sec)</small><sup>1</sup></td>
      <td><b>USD 0.99</b> <small>/month</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Archive <small>(10 years)</small><sup>2</sup></td>
      <td><b>USD 1.99</b> <small>/month</small></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Why does the sample above work but not on https://dev.meteo.cam/pricing on small screens?

PS: When I insert the CSS on https://dev.meteo.cam/pricing via Chrome Inspector, it works also!

Comment: It's working..no overlapping issue..did you check in real device or chrome responsive tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked it in my browser and `table.table-complex td` has a `white-space:nowrap` styling element. This is causing the problem you're having. It is part of the `tags.css` file.

Comment: Thank you, just this moment I was also seeing this additional CSS style for small screens...